# 960 grid system with sidebar?

Tags: 960.gs

I've prepared this lovely little image:

[image]

This is essentially what I need to achieve.

Im using the [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/)

Is it even possible?

Ive tried this:

```
<div class="grid_8"></div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="grid_4"></div>
<div class="grid_4"></div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="grid_4"></div>
<div class="grid_4"></div>
```

but i dont know how id put the sidebar in!!

**edit**

i just tried hierarchy like so:

```
<div class="grid_8">
    <div class="grid_4"></div>
    <div class="grid_4"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="grid_4"></div>
    <div class="grid_4"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid_4"></div>
```

but that mega failed :(

Comment: Yes, it is possible (not joking).

Comment: have you looked at the demo page? http://960.gs/demo.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to nest the `.grid_4` and `.grid_8` content divs in a `.grid_8`:

```
<div class="grid_8">
    <div class="grid_8 alpha omega"></div>
    <div class="grid_4 alpha"></div>
    <div class="grid_4 omega"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid_4"></div>
```